# C# Winform/XNA QUestion

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a panel for my 2d objects to appear from using xna. THe objects are being controlled with the arrow keys. But after I started to add winform buttons. when i run the program the arrow keys are now just controlling the buttons and not the 2d object.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to explain more. I really didn't understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you seem to have is that the controls you have in your form receive the actions before your form does.

If that is so, try to set the [`Form.KeyPreview Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) to true.

**Form.KeyPreview Property**

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.